# Why are the "normal" methods for generating random integers so slow?

Tags: python, performance, random

Not a maths major or a cs major, I just fool around with python (usually making scripts for simulations/theorycrafting on video games) and I discovered just how bad random.randint is performance wise. It's got me wondering why random.randint or random.randrange are used/made the way they are. I made a function that produces (for all intents and actual purposes) identical results to random.randint:

```
big_bleeping_float= (2**64 - 2)/(2**64 - 2)
def fastrandint(start, stop):
  return start + int(random.random() * (stop - start + big_bleeping_float))
```

There is a massive 180% speed boost using that to generate an integer in the range (inclusive) 0-65 compared to random.randrange(0, 66), the next fastest method.

```
>>> timeit.timeit('random.randint(0, 66)', setup='from numpy import random', number=10000)
0.03165552873121058

>>> timeit.timeit('random.randint(0, 65)', setup='import random', number=10000)
0.022374771118336412

>>> timeit.timeit('random.randrange(0, 66)', setup='import random', number=10000)
0.01937231027605435

>>> timeit.timeit('fastrandint(0, 65)', setup='import random; from fasterthanrandomrandom import fastrandint', number=10000)
0.0067909916844523755
```

Furthermore, the adaptation of this function as an alternative to random.choice is 75% faster, and I'm sure adding larger-than-one stepped ranges would be faster (although I didn't test that). For almost double the speed boost as using the fastrandint function you can simply write it inline:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('int(random.random() * (65 + big_bleeping_float))', setup='import random; big_bleeping_float= (2**64 - 2)/(2**64 - 2)', number=10000)
0.0037642723021917845
```

So in summary, why am I wrong that my function is a better, why is it faster if it is better, and is there a yet even faster way to do what I'm doing?

Comment: Isn't (2 ** 64 - 2)/(2 ** 64 - 2) just 1? Why are you adding it?

Comment: The +1 masquerading as big_bleeping_float is actually required, since `random()*N` generates values from `(0,N]` and applying int to this rounds down, giving ints in (0,N-1)

Comment: @Michael Anderson: yes but why not adding simply 1?

Comment: Oh, I have no idea why it's not just written as +1, or why it's called `big_bleeping_float` - just that it is actually required for the values to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

`random.randint()` and others are calling into `random.getrandbits()` which may be less efficient that direct calls to `random()`, but for good reason.

It is actually more correct to use a `randint` that calls into `random.getrandbits()`, as it can be done in an unbiased manner.

You can see that using random.random to generate values in a range ends up being biased since there are only M floating point values between 0 and 1 (for M pretty large). Take an N that doesn't divide into M, then if we write M = k N + r for `0<r<N`. At best, using `random.random() * (N+1)`
we'll get `r` numbers coming out with probability (k+1)/M and `N-r` numbers coming out with probability `k/M`. (This is *at best*, using the pigeon hole principle - in practice I'd expect the bias to be even worse).

Note that this bias is only noticeable for

- A large number of sampling
- where N is a large fraction of M the number of floats in (0,1]

So it probably won't matter to you, unless you know you need unbiased values - such as for scientific computing etc.

In contrast, a value from `randint(0,N)` can be unbiased by using rejection sampling from repeated calls to `random.getrandbits()`. Of course managing this can introduce additional overhead.

**Aside**

If you end up using a custom random implementation then

From the [python 3 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html)

> Almost all module functions depend on the basic function random(), which 
>   generates a random float uniformly in the semi-open range [0.0, 1.0).

This suggests that `randint` and others may be implemented using `random.random`. If this is the case I would expect them to be slower,
incurring at least one addition function call overhead per call.

Looking at the code referenced in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37540577/221955 you can see that this will happen if the random implementation doesn't provide a `getrandbits()` function.

Answer (score 2):

[`randint`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/random.py#l214) calls [`randrange`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/random.py#l170) which does a bunch of range/type checks and conversions and then uses [`_randbelow`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/random.py#l220) to generate a random int. `_randbelow` again does some range checks and finally uses [`random`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/random.py#l647).

So if you remove all the checks for edge cases and some function call overhead, it's no surprise your `fastrandint` is quicker.

Comment: Actually `_randbelow` doesn't (usually) call `random`, it calls `getrandbits()` and loops to remove (reduce) bias.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably rarely a problem but `randint(0,10**1000)` works while `fastrandint(0,10**1000)` crashes. The slower time is probably the price you need to pay to have a function that works for all possible cases...